# Javascript html5 locations button

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

```
<script>
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_position);
//This function does the work of getting the actual user coordinates
 function show_position(position){

var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var longi = position.coords.longitude;
var tick = position.timestamp;

document.getElementById("Coord1").innerHTML=lat;
document.getElementById("Coord2").innerHTML=longi;

}
</script>

 <p>Your Latitude is: <b id="Coord1" style="color:blue;"> </b></p>
 <p>Your Longitude is: <b id="Coord2" style="color:blue;"> </b> </p>
```

Hi everyone,

I am trying to run this code and it seems to be working properly. However, is it possible to create a javascript button that runs `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_position);`? I have a search box and i want a button right next to it and when a user clicks it, it automatically fills out the empty box and then searches. Dont know if thats possible or not.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You could run the navigator.geolocation on a click event

```
    x$("#btnInit").click(loadDemo); 
    //run the function
    function loadDemo() { 
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_position);
//This function does the work of getting the actual user coordinates
 function show_position(position){

var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var longi = position.coords.longitude;
var tick = position.timestamp;

document.getElementById("Coord1").innerHTML=lat;
document.getElementById("Coord2").innerHTML=longi;

}
}
```

I a using xuijs hence the x$ in front of the button. Its the same as document.getElementById("btnInit")

then have a button with the id of btnInit on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
document.getElementById('getPositionBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {          
       document.getElementById("Coord1").innerHTML=position.coords.latitude;
       document.getElementById("Coord2").innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;
    });
});
</script>

<p>Your Latitude is: <b id="Coord1" style="color:blue;"> </b></p>
<p>Your Longitude is: <b id="Coord2" style="color:blue;"> </b> </p><br>
<button id="getPositionBtn">Get Position!</button>
```